# Can NetSuite replace WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, etc.? (As of May 2014.)

Tags: netsuite

As of May 2014... how feasible is it for NetSuite to replace a full-blown CMS such as WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, etc.?

All these are written in PHP and usually use a MySQL database and with all the server-side modules now-a-day, PHP is pretty much limitless... I'm wondering what the NetSuite/SuiteScript limitations are, or perhaps, there's a way to write direct Java... but then again it sounds like there's not a lot of database options from NetSuite, etc.

It's looking like the server-side SuiteScript Server Pages (SSP) has become a lot more powerful and when used with everything they mention: SuiteTalk, RESTlets, Suitelets, node.js, etc... Can it replace a full CMS?

After talking with numerous NetSuite employees, the answer I get is "well it depends on the site" or "I'm sure that's possible, just hire this consultant", etc...

So, what I'm really trying to ask is about comparing NetSuite to standard Content-Management-System features that usually exist in all the major CMS packages...

i.e.

- Author tools, content authoring, and content management
- Content lifespan management and content approval
- Versioning and auditing; audit and archive
- Content structure
- Web forms
- Content sharing
- Reports, analytics, and monitoring
- Performance and capability
- Security and access management
- Usability
- Compliance
- Portability, reuse, external content, and additional features

etc... (https://www.cwp.govt.nz/features/capability-of-the-content-management-system/)

---

**Professional Experience or Opinions?**

> I welcome any professional experience or opinions... and any experiences you can
>   share about building large article-based websites (what you'd
>   typically see on WordPress, Drupal or Joomla) in NetSuite. So
>   basically way beyond the cookie-cutter store templates that you
>   usually see on NetSuite websites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NetSuite seems to be well aware of their shortcoming on offering feasible CMS features… so… about 2 months ago, NetSuite bought LightCMS:
http://www.lightcms.com/element-fusion-the-creator-of-lightcms-joins-forces-with-netsuite

LightCMS is by nature “light” and will not have quite the depth of features that WordPress, Drupal or Joomla might have... but it looks like it will be fairly feasible.

LightCMS makes it easy to set up contact forms, surveys, registrations, and more. Form entries can be emailed to you or exported to excel or CSV. You can even accept payments through your forms!

LightCMS also, has a good portion of the standard CMS features that we’d need, like: automatic archiving, pagination, tagging / categories, comments with moderation and advanced spam protection, pings, pingbacks, RSS, etc.